# Using JS inside VF page to redirect to another VF Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have 3 pages, a homepage and then two other pages. Depending on what the user clicks on in the homepage I want to redirect them to one of the two other VF pages. How would I do this using JS or JQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
$('#youritem').click(function(){
    window.location = '{!urlfor($Page.yourpagenamehere)}';
});
```

Complicated answer:  You need to consider why you're doing this instead of just using an apex:outputLink with the value set to the same as the above.  If you're doing it because you have some special handler on the item then that makes some sense, but otherwise I'd do the following to redirect pages:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!urlfor($Page.yourpagenamehere)}">Link Title</apex:outputLink>
```

Or use a commandLink with an action that calls into a controller or extension method that returns a PageReference (PageReference auto redirects on return from action type tags).